# Adding packages to Julia on WSL

Tags: julia

I wanted to add a julia package (JuMP) to my julia on windows subsystem for linux, but the operation got interrupted. When I tried it again, I get the error Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Calculus (...). I tried removing it, but it says "not found in project or mainfest". Can I somehow fix this (without reinstalling julia)? I tried first adding Calculus, but it says it has no known versions. Thanks

[image: error screenshot]

Edit: already reinstalled julia, so solved for me. I will keep the question up, if anyone encounters the same error.

Comment: Can you post the error message? The fact that it got interrupted the first time might be a coincidence. There could be a dependency restriction which is preventing JuMP from being installed.

Comment: actually, that was the second time this happened, so I dont think that was a coincidence. I still have the old files as a backup, so I will post it here, if anyone encounters the same problem, but I already just reinstalled julia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you interrupt package installation the state of Julia package repository can remain corrupt.
In result, in some cases, the only feasible solution is either to delete your `.julia` folder (which is usually in your `HOME` directory or set a new value for the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` variable pointing to a new empty directory location for your Julia package repository.

Unfortunately, since package installers perform many distinct steps, it seems there is no good other solution to repair a broken package repository (as of the current Julia version 1.5.2). The good news is that you do not need to reinstall Julia.